# MATLAB Based Root Estimation Tool

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to develop a MATLAB function that very quickly solves roots. I have already developed 4 functions that use different root-estimation methods(Newton's, Secant, False Position, and Bisection). I want to stitch these functions together to create a function that estimates the root to an input percision very quickly. Is there a particular method I should stick to or should I develop some sort of logic system to decide which method touse. The input function will always have a root within a predefined range.

I haven't started development yet. My initial plan was to stick to just using bisection because it is reliable.